# How to know what beans are not in use?

Tags: performance, panels, blocks

After looking into new-relic I found that bean_block_info was taking a high % of total load time. In the code I found that this function loads all the beans on first time access (before leveraging cache on subsequent loads). I have thousands of beans which were created over past few years and many of which may be not in use. Most of the beans are added via panelizers.

Is there a quick way/script to find out which beans are not in use? I will remove them so that the first time load time is improved.

Comment: Do you use the drupal core blocks UI or the context module or any other block management systems, or just panels?

Comment: @rooby Its mostly added on nodes for which panelizer is enabled

Comment: Mostly and all are very different in terms of what script you would need to run.

Comment: @rooby do you have any script which can get the list assuming that all beans are used on panelizer?